# restore feature in in-app purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I am using in-app purchase in my application. Everything is working fine.
User can buy, restore transaction properly.

I have 1 issue in restore feature:

How do I implement - user can't restore without buying any item, because when user click on restore button without buying any item then it goes for restoring and app is blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to implement the web-service just few lines of codes solve the issue -

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
int totalNumberOfPurchaseToBeRestored = queue.transactions.count;
if (totalNumberOfPurchaseToBeRestored == 0)
{
    //No item found for Restore"
}
else
{
        // Restore items
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When your transaction is finished, then update the ProductPurchased. And check the value of ProductPurchased in viewDidLoad & set the restore button accordingly. Check the below code which may help you & let me know.

```
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"ProductPurchased"]intValue]==1)
       restoreButton.hidden=YES;
```

Write the following code in restore transaction complete transaction method.

```
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ProductPurchased"] == 0)
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"ProductPurchased"];
   self.viewController.restoreButton.hidden=YES;
}
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ProductPurchased"] == 0)
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"ProductPurchased"];
   self.viewController.restoreButton.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: Means you are saying show the restore button when User successfully buy any item.

Comment: exactly, because before buying any item, there is no need of restore. If this solves your answer then upvote & accept:)

Comment: First time when user download the app then restore button is hidden,once he buy any item then i will show the restore button. And with the same login user downloaded the app in different device then how it works,because restore button is hidden but he already purchased.

Comment: If user already purchased any item & you used non-consumable in-app, then apple handles it. If you want it globally(user specific), then you need to use web services.

Comment: Thank you so much @Girish i am implementing this,I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: If we have any idea to check from apple any item is already purchased or not then i think restore feature will be easily implemented:)

Comment: Instead of that, simply write one web-service which stores productid & userid. On app launch, check if current user is already purchased any product, if yes then show restore button else hide it.

Comment: @Girish i have a point regarding your opinion as you mention in your comments, you mention that "If user already purchased any item & you used non-consumable in-app, then apple handles it" but if we set the value for hidden the restore button by us then how can this flow will be handle by apple?

Comment: @ArunSharma are you able to do this with restore functionality? please help me on same.

Comment: @sandy i posted the Answer you can see in the Answer.